# How to get oauth access token using puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

I need to first fetch the oauth access token and then pass it as a parameter to my post request,
please let me know how this can be achieved using puppeteer.

I am new to puppeteer and I am stuck kindly assist.

Answer (score -1):

Was unable to find an appropirate way to resolve the issue with puppeteer, I resolved it using Axios

Comment: Can you provide your code, or an overview of how you approached this?